# Can i use for loop here instead of writing hundred lines of code.

Tags: javascript

This is my function. now its suck when there is 200 id.i don't want to write till 200 id's. can i use for loop here ? like this

```
for(i=0;i<200;i++){
  "areas": [ {"id": i}]
}
```

> this is my function

```
var continentsDataProvider = {
 "map": "continentsLow",

"areas": [ {
  "id": 1,
}, {
  "id": "2",
}, {
 }, {
  "id": "3",
}, {
 }, {
  "id": "4",
}, {
 }, {
  "id": "5",
}, {
  } ]

};
```

Comment: so you want an array with 200 objects?

Comment: Yes, you may. But not like `"areas": [ {"id": i}]`. Use `continentsDataProvider.areas.push({id: i});` where `continentsDataProvider` is an object containing `areas` as empty array.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for your reply.yes i want an array. i got my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, simply try

If your object is

```
var continentsDataProvider = {
  "map": "continentsLow",
  "areas": []
};
```

Run your for-loop as

```
for(var i=1;i<=200;i++){
  continentsDataProvider.areas.push( {"id": i});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop to create the objects or you can use (the much nicer) [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
var continentsDataProvider = {
  "map": "continentsLow",

  "areas": Array.from({ length: 200 }, function(k, v) { return { id: v + 1}; })
};

console.log(continentsDataProvider);
```

As noted by **Emil S. Jørgensen** in the comments - `Array.from` is not supported by internet explorer so you'll need to polyfill it ([polyfill code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill)).

Comment: Remember to polyfill or prepare to lose IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Indeed. I'll add it to the answer.